# What is the song that play while gon use jajanken?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

What is the song that play while gon uses Jajanken in greed Island arc???
I don't know exactly but it is a track that is played when he uses the full power jajanken against Razor in Soufurabi.. while playing Dodge ball...

Comment: Please specify which episode, including the approximate time and specific description of when it occurs.

Comment: I don't know exactly but it is a track that is played when he uses the full power jajanken against Razor in Soufurabi.. while playing Dodge ball...

Answer (score 1):

[The Emperor's Time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJIUT85xGak) by 平野義久 , Album : HUNTER×HUNTER セレクトｘベストｘα.

You'll find the details in the description of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25KjGiYBndY) of the battle you mentioned in the comment.